# Подсказки dadata на мобильном устройстве

Tags: javascript

я использую сервис dadata для получения подсказок при вводе адреса с последующей декомпозицией полного адреса на его составляющие(Область, Город, Улица и т.д.). На ПК версии приложения все работает хорошо, однако при попытке сделать тоже самое с мобильного устройства при вводе адреса подсказки появляются, но при нажатии на нее адрес не заносится в поле и не происходит декомпозиция по полям. Использую код с примера на dadata, его приложу ниже. Я так понимаю не срабатывает onSelect. Скажите пожалуйста, как я могу решить эту проблему ? Ниже будет пример используемого кода.

```
$("[Data-test-ID = 'Input_Address']").suggestions({
    token: "Тут ключ API",
    type: "ADDRESS",
    count: 5,
    /* Вызывается, когда пользователь выбирает одну из подсказок */
    onSelect: function(suggestion) {
      alert("Обработчик сработал");
        console.log(suggestion);

       $("[Data-test-ID = 'Full1']").val(suggestion.unrestricted_value);
       $("[Data-test-ID = 'Flat1']").val(suggestion.data.block);
       $("[Data-test-ID = 'City1']").val(suggestion.data.city);
       if (suggestion.data.city == null)
        {
          $("[Data-test-ID = 'City1']").val(suggestion.data.settlement); 
        }
       $("[Data-test-ID = 'Street1']").val(suggestion.data.street);
       $("[Data-test-ID = 'House1']").val(suggestion.data.house);
       $("[Data-test-ID = 'Region1']").val(suggestion.data.region);
       $("[Data-test-ID = 'postal_code1']").val(suggestion.data.postal_code);
       $("[Data-test-ID = 'ID1']").val(sek);

    }
});
```

Comment: `при нажатии на нее адрес не заносится в поле и не происходит декомпозиция по полям` — где весь код?

Comment: Прошу прощения, исправил

Comment: А html-код где?

Comment: Вообще вполне возможно что на мобильном в виджете suggestions нет обработки события tap, а есть только click

Answer (score 0):

Для начала убедитесь, что данные приходят: `console.info` использовать не можем, поэтому возьмите `alert`

```
$("[Data-test-ID = 'Input_Address']").suggestions({
    token: "Тут ключ API",
    type: "ADDRESS",
    count: 5,
    /* Вызывается, когда пользователь выбирает одну из подсказок */
    onSelect: function(suggestion) {
    alert(suggestion.unrestricted_value);
    alert(suggestion.data.block);
    alert(suggestion.data.city);
    alert(suggestion.data.street);
    alert(suggestion.data.house);
    alert(suggestion.data.region);
    alert(suggestion.data.postal_code);
    }
});
```

Но я уверен, что здесь всё в порядке. Проблема ваша скорее всего заключается в написании идентификатора в разном регистре. Если написать `data-Text="text"` то браузер переведет его в нижний регистр, поэтому вам придется работать не с `data-Text`, а с `data-text`.

Переведите свои идентификаторы в нижний регистр и я думаю проблема исчезнет